# Recursively delete folders below 3rd level in large structure of folders

Tags: python, recursion, directory

I have a large structure of thousands of folders only, however I am only interested in keeping the folders in the top three levels, and deleting the rest. I am looking for a recursive python script to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but it will probably look something like this with `os.walk()`:

```
import os
import shutil

BASE = '.'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(BASE):
    n = 0
    head = root
    while head and head != BASE:
        head, _ = os.path.split(head)
        n += 1
    if n == 3:
        for dir in dirs:
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, dir))
        del dirs[:]      # clear dirs so os.walk() doesn't look for subdirectories
```

Comment: +1. But theoretically, separator characters aren't necessarily separators wherever they appear. If Python is ported to a system where '/foo/bar\/baz/qux' has components 'foo', 'bar/baz', 'qux', or where [foo\bar]:baz\qux has components 'baz' and 'qux' on volume 'foo\bar', os.path.dirname (and walk, split, etc.) will work, but counting/splitting on/etc. os.sep will not.

Comment: @abarnert, good point, I have edited my answer and it should now handle that case properly.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is with `os.walk`, but here's a cheap answer:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('rm -rf */*/*/*/*')
>>> os.system('rmdir */*/*/*')
```

This will remove all files at least four levels in, and then try to remove all directories rooted at least three levels in. Since the previous command will have removed their contents, the `rmdir` will succeed (and complain about all non-directory leaves it finds).